# Filter objects over 0000-00-00 date in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to simply get objects which contract_time set to "0000-00-00"
I've tried:

```
users = MonitoringUsers.objects.filter(contract_time = "0000-00-00")
```

But it throws Validation Error: year is out of range

I connect to the different system, I cannot change how this objects are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can't convert this string to correct `date` object so you have to use queryset's [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method:

```
users = MonitoringUsers.objects.extra(where=["contract_time='0000-00-00'"])
```

To prevent errors while loading such records you have to [`defer`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer) this field:

```
users = MonitoringUsers.objects.defer('contract_time').all()
```

You can iterate this queryset as usual but if you will try to access `user.contract_time` for "0000-00-00" record you will get the same `ValueError`.  To solve this issue add a simple property to `MonitoringUsers`:

```
class MonitoringUsers(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def contract_time_or_none(self):
        try:
            return self.contract_time
        except ValueError:
            return None
```

Your template in this case will look like:

```
<ul>
{% for user in users %}
    <li>
        {{ user }} -
        {{ user.contract_time_or_none|default:"END of contract" }}
    </li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

But you should understand that loading of deferred field means additional db hit for each instance of `MonitoringUsers`.  If you want to avoid this then you have to convert date-to-string at SQL level. I don't know which SQL server you use so here is example for SQLite:

```
users = MonitoringUsers.objects.defer('contract_time').extra(
           select={'contract_time_str':
                   'CASE WHEN contract_time="0000-00-00" '
                         'THEN "END of contract" '
                         'ELSE strftime("%Y-%m-%d", contract_time) '
                   'END'})
```

With this solution you can output `contract_time_str` as is:

```
<ul>
{% for user in users %}
    <li>
        {{ user }} - {{ user.contract_time_str }}
    </li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Of course in this scenario there will be no additional queries to database.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :) But how can I display in template, for example I use: MonitoringUsers.objects.all() and in views and loop in template and I would like to display "END of contract" for those objects which have contract_time set to "0000-00-00"

Answer (score 0):

We used to have a table in MySQL with `0000-00-00` in date fields. Our work around wasn't quite as complicated as @catavaran's answer.

Like in the question, we got a `ValidationError` when trying `MonitoringUsers.objects.filter(contract_time="0000-00-00")`.

So to filter these users, we could use `extra()` as @catavaran suggests.

When accessing `contract_time` for a record with `0000-00-00`, we found that the Django ORM returned `None`

```
>>> users = MonitoringUsers.objects.extra(where=["contract_time='0000-00-00'"])
>>> for user in users:
...     print repr(user.contract_time) 
None
```

Therefore, in the template, we could simply use:

```
{{ user.contract_time|default:"END of contract" }}
```

and we didn't have to do a `defer()` or add a `select` argument to extra.

This is simply what we found. Different MySQL versions/configurations may vary. Eventually, we were able to convert all the `0000-00-00`s to nulls.